# Estimote beacon only detect the nearest beacon

Tags: angularjs, ibeacon, region, proximity, estimote

I'm developing an audiotour in a museum. I'm using 4 beacons and 4 sections. The only problem is that i've got a region where 2 of the beacons are detected by my device.

The region of a beacon starts an audiofile and when it exits the region it stops. When I'm in the middle of two overlapping regions it wil stop/start audiofiles. What results in 'stop audio beacon_1' - 'start audio beacon_2' | 'start audio beacon_1' - 'stop audio beacon_2'. It causes to falter the audiofiles.

Now, my question is: how can i detect the closest beacon without interference by the other beacon?

Comment: :-
Hey... did you solve your issue?

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately. I've put a timer on the signal that the beacon sends. My page or my sound will start when your phone receives the beacon-signal three times in a row. Its a lame work-around but the only thing I could do in the short amount of time that I had. 

I'm starting a new project within two weeks were this problem must be solved. If so, I'll post it here!